# Round edges in gauge chart using C3.js

Tags: javascript, angular, web, d3.js, c3.js

I'm using C3.js with D3.js to build a full circle gauge chart. I want to create round edges on the progress arc.
I have already tried the CSS property `stoke-linejoin: round` applied to the path element but it didn't work.

[image: Current gauge chart]

Comment: Can you add code first

Comment: Which part? JS or CSS?